# How to make router-link consume parent v-on:click completely

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

```
<parent v-on:click="isActive = !isActive">
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">{{tag}}</router-link>
</parent>
```

If the `router-link` is clicked the `v-on:click` in the parent will still capture the event.

How to make the `router-link` consume the click event completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok found a workaround. Since `router-link` renders an `a` then the `v-on:click.stop` is not propagated to that rendered `a`. But if you wrap it with a `div` which contains the stop, it will work.

```
<parent v-on:click="isActive = !isActive">
  <div v-on:click.stop>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">{{tag}}</router-link>
  </div>
</parent>
```

Comment: of course! thats perfect. Hopefully they update `router-link` to enable this feature